# How to use sort on an awk print command?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a couple of commands in an awk script I'm writing:

```awk
print "Here are some players and their numbers, sorted by last name"
if(sum[x] > 500) {print x, $2}
```

Which outputs:

```
Here are some players and their numbers, sorted by last name
Lebron James 23
Kevin Durant 35
Kobe Bryant 24
Blake Griffin 32
Dikembe Mutumbo 55
```

How can I use the `sort` command **in my awk script** to sort the players and their numbers ONLY?

Comment: Given your comments on the answers, you seem to be confusing **awk** and **shell** script in your question. It seems that you wish to do the sorting _within your awk script_, not in the _shell_ script invoking it. If that is correct, then please edit your question and replace the two occurrences of 'shell' by 'awk'. On a separate note: yes, awk has a sorting facility, but it is quite involved: you must store all lines in an array, keyed on their second field, which you'll need to extract from `x`, then set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to a cryptic value, then output the array. I wouldn't go there.

Comment: I mean: I wouldn't go there given the simplicity of `... | sort -k2,2`.

Comment: @zwets How would I implement `...| sort -k2,2` if there are other lines that need to be printed? Check edited question.

Comment: By `echo`-ing the header line from the shell, then run the `awk | sort` pipeline.

Answer (score 12):

you can add `| sort -k2` to your command. This will sort alphabetically based on the second column.

Example:

```
$ echo "Lebron James 23
Kevin Durant 35
Kobe Bryant 24
Blake Griffin 32
Dikembe Mutumbo 55" | sort -k2
```

results in

```
Kobe Bryant 24
Kevin Durant 35
Blake Griffin 32
Lebron James 23
Dikembe Mutumbo 55
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using a script, and the sort command will be mashed up with many other outputs. Is there a way to sort the output of `{print x, $2}` directly in the script code? I'm getting an error when piping `if(sum[x] > 500) {print x, $2} | sort -k2`.

Comment: @KMoy: `if(sum[x] > 500) {print x, $2}` is Awk code while `| sort -k2` is a shell command. Obviously you can't mix the two like that because they're different languages. Instead you need to apply the `sort` command to the output of the Awk interpreter that runs your Awk code snippet. If you don't know what I mean please expand your question to give us the full picture.

Comment: You are writing a shell script, right? Then you have two option: 1. run `./my-script.sh | sort -k2`. 2. add  ` | sort -k2` to the line of your script that produces the output given in your question.

Comment: @Wayne_Yux Please check edits made to original question.

Comment: Then you probably need the answer from @steeldriver

Answer (score 9):

Although I wouldn't recommend it (given the relative simplicity of piping the result through an external `sort` command) you can do this at least with recent versions of GNU awk (at least 4.0 IIRC), as described at [Sorting Array Values and Indices with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html#Array-Sorting-Functions)

Here's how you could implement it, assuming you have the data in an associative array in which the index is `Firstname Lastname`. First you need to define a custom comparison function that splits the index, compares first on `Lastname` then (as a tie breaker) on `Firstname` e.g.

```bsh
function mycmp(ia, va, ib, vb, sa, sb) {
  if(split(toupper(ia), sa) && split(toupper(ib), sb)) {
    if(sa[2] < sb[2]) return -1;
    else if (sa[2] > sb[2]) return 1;
    else {
      # compare first names
      if(sa[1] < sb[1]) return -1;
      else if (sa[1] > sb[1]) return 1;
      else return 0;
    }
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

Now you can use the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` array sorting method mentioned in comments by @zwets

```bsh
PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "mycmp";
for(i in a) print i, a[i];
```

Putting it together

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

function mycmp(ia, va, ib, vb, sa, sb) {
  if(split(toupper(ia), sa) && split(toupper(ib), sb)) {
    if(sa[2] < sb[2]) return -1;
    else if (sa[2] > sb[2]) return 1;
    else {
      # compare first names
      if(sa[1] < sb[1]) return -1;
      else if (sa[1] > sb[1]) return 1;
      else return 0;
    }
  }
  else return 0;
}

{
  a[$1" "$2] = $3;
}

END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "mycmp";
  for(i in a) print i, a[i];
}
```

Testing:

```
$ ./namesort.awk yourfile
Kobe Bryant 24
Kevin Durant 35
Blake Griffin 32
Lebron James 23
Dikembe Mutumbo 55
```

---

In lesser or older versions of awk, your best bet may be to store the data indexed by `Lastname Firstname` instead, sort with the conventional `asorti`, then split and swap the fields of the indices as you traverse the array to print it:

```bsh
awk '
  {a[$2" "$1]=$3} 
  END {
    n=asorti(a,b); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {split(b[i],s); print s[2], s[1], a[b[i]]}
}' yourfile
```

Answer (score 5):

To `sort` only by the whitespace separated second field, use key `-k2,2`:

```
... | sort -k2,2
```

by default `sort` does the sorting lexicographically.

Note that, if you don't mention the last field for the sorting key i.e. if you just use `-k2` then you might not get the desired result as this will `sort` according to *all fields* starting from second.

Also check `man sort`.

Comment: Please check comment on Wayne's post for what I need

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk -f myscript.awk | sort -k2
```

Where myscript.awk contains purely awk commands.

If your actual script is a shell script, you have several options including

- Pipe output through sort. `./myscript.bash | sort -k2`
- Rewrite code as a function inside the script
  Instead of

  ```
  $ cat t1
  #!/bin/bash
  for i in 2 4 3 1 5;
  do
    echo $i
  done

  $ ./t1
  2
  4
  3
  1
  5
  ```

  Do

  ```
  $ cat t2
  #!/bin/bash
  function foo {
    for i in 2 4 3 1 5;
    do
      echo $i
    done
  }
  foo | sort

  $ ./t2
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  ```

But note you can also apply the sort to the do...done structure instead of making a function.

```
    do
       echo $i
    done | sort
```

Comment: Why define the function?

Comment: @zwets, it makes it easier to feed the results of arbitrary code, including looping control structures, through a pipeline. There  are cases where it is unnecessary but I find it a useful general pattern. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

To sort your data to print:

- Suppose you want to print 2nd field (whitespace separated) use this:

  ```
  awk '{print $2}' data.txt | sort
  ```

  e.g.:

  ```
  $cat>data.txt
  1 Kedar 20
  2 Amit 30
  3 Rahul 21
  ^C

  $awk '{print $2}' | sort
  Amit
  Kedar
  Rahul
  ```
- If you want to print the whole of your `data.txt` but sorted on column 2, then:

  ```
  $awk '{print}'|sort -k2
  2 Amit 30
  1 Kedar 20
  3 Rahul 21
  ```

Use this logic(s) in your requirement.

You may use `man sort` for more interesting features of `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "Here are some players and their numbers, sorted by last name"
if(sum[x] > 500) {print x, $2 | "sort -k2,2"}
```

To sort the output to a file:

```
print "Here are some players and their numbers, sorted by last name"
if(sum[x] > 500) {print x, $2 | "sort -k2,2 > sortedFile"}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about below:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{str="1\n2\n3\n4"; system("echo -e \""str"\" | sort -r")}'
```

it work when i tested.